# nav (with some buttons positioned right) at bottom of div

Tags: css, css-position

I'm trying to achieve a menu very similar to the one here:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_topnav_right

except - I want it to be at the bottom of a div.
(If you can imagine an image box that has that kind of nav bar at the bottom - with the image on the layer below the menu because I might want it to show through a partial opacity).

I thought it would be very simple with a bit of absolute and relative positioning. But I'm getting really messed up, with the contents of the nav being moved about, and the buttons to the right moving left.

Comment: Please post text as text, not as an image.  It's really not much effort to copy-paste yoour HTML etc.

Comment: I'm not sure  understand. I have included no images.

Comment: You are right its not an image, but it may as well be.  Why do I have to click a link to see your code.  Please copy/paste it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<header>
    <nav class="main">...</nav>
    <nav class="sub">...</nav>
</header>
```

just apply `space-between` to header element:

```
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!
From very quickly (so probably did it horribly) sticking that in, seems to have done the trick nicely.
https://jsfiddle.net/q89Lzgra/

Only concern is mobile screens. Not used flex so have to look up how best to handle, but there's always media queries at a push.

Comment: You can target a mobile screen with media queries and then make it a collapsible top down menu. Or just hide it completely and use something else on mobile.